# How to draw lines across cells in a WPF Grid

Tags: wpf, grid

I am trying to fill the Grid control with custom controls dynamically. After the grid is filled with elements, I need to connect these elements by lines. How do I achieve this....

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea you could try: Within a Grid, items will overlap each other.  So you could create an outer Grid which contains your grid and also a Canvas with a transparent background.  On the Canvas, you could draw lines which would look like they are connecting your Grid's elements.

Comment: I like decyclone's answer a lot better, but I'm not sure whether I should delete this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Grid` set as an `ItemsPanel` for an `ItemsControl`. It's not quite easy, but if that's the way you want to go.

For connecting elements by a line, here is a good article that shows you just that:

[UI Frontiers: Thinking Outside the Grid (by Charles Petzold)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff646962.aspx)

[image]